# jooq sql builder output give "?" at eq() in WHERE clause

Tags: sql, jooq

I copy the example code [here](https://www.jooq.org/doc/3.14/manual/getting-started/use-cases/jooq-as-a-standalone-sql-builder/):

The whole code block look like this

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import org.jooq.DSLContext;
import org.jooq.SQLDialect;
import static org.jooq.impl.DSL.*;


public static String sampleSql() {
    DSLContext create = DSL.using(SQLDialect.MYSQL);
    String sql = create.select(field("BOOK.TITLE"), field("AUTHOR.FIRST_NAME"), field("AUTHOR.LAST_NAME"))
            .from(table("BOOK"))
            .join(table("AUTHOR"))
            .on(field("BOOK.AUTHOR_ID").eq(field("AUTHOR.ID")))
            .where(field("BOOK.PUBLISHED_IN").eq(1948))
            .getSQL();
    return sql;
}
```

The output of `sampleSql()` is

```
select BOOK.TITLE, AUTHOR.FIRST_NAME, AUTHOR.LAST_NAME from BOOK join AUTHOR on BOOK.AUTHOR_ID = AUTHOR.ID where BOOK.PUBLISHED_IN = ?
```

But why the question mark "?", the question mark should be 1948. WHat did I miss ?

Comment: This is a frequent question among new jOOQ users. Thanks for linking to the relevant tutorial section, which might have led to the confusion here. We'll improve it right away: https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/10053

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`getSQL()` returns the prepared statement with ? as parameter placeholders.

If you want to inline the parameters you have to call:

```
getSQL(ParamType.INLINED);
```

Please find the API Docs here: https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org.jooq/org/jooq/Query.html